# Submit Spark Jobs in EMR concurrently from Lambda

Tags: apache-spark, emr

My application has requirement to real time processing data using EMR spark Jobs.

I am using addJobFlowSteps API of EMR from Lambda, but which is sequential in nature.

Is there any other way to submit Jobs to EMR from Lambda which is concurrent in nature ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom 'spark-submit' script.

I use this:

```
cat /usr/bin/spark-submit-forked
#!/bin/bash

(nohup spark-submit "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 &)
```